# Как использовать картинки с других сайтов, соблюдая лицензию?

Tags: поддержка, авторские-права

Вижу где-то в интернете картинку, которая бы хорошо проиллюстрировала мое сообщение (например, на Википедии). Можно ли ее использовать? Как это правильно сделать в зависимости от лицензии? Что из этого нужно делать:

- Дать ссылку на страницу картинки в Википедии?
- Явно указать автора в моем сообщении?
- Написать, что взято из Википедии?

Для других сайтов:

- Что делать, если лицензия не указана?

Comment: с точки зрения здравого смысла, *url* картинки **уже** является «отсылкой» к первоисточнику. но проблемы авторских прав **иногда** от него (здравого смысла) несколько далеки.

Comment: http://www.wtfpl.net/

Comment: @igumnov: почитал. Отличная лицензия ))